# c# assert that a sequence of integer are incremental

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm writing a unit test to assert against the properties of a collection of objects. One of the properties is an integer which is supposed to be incremented by one for each object in the collection. There is no guarantee however that the order in which the items were added to the collection is the same order that they are "sequenced", if you catch my meaning.

I'd like to be able to write an assertion statement to the effect that:

```
public class Something 
{
    public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void SomethingSequenceNumberTest()
{
    var lotsOfThings = new List<Something>
    {
        new Something { SequenceNumber = 1 },
        new Something { SequenceNumber = 2 },
        new Something { SequenceNumber = 4 },
        new Something { SequenceNumber = 3 },
    }

    // Assert that a sequence of integer are incremental, that there are no repetitions or gaps.

    Assert....?
}
```

Comment: Just hard code the values `Assert.AreEqual(1, lotsOfThings[0].SequenceNumber)` your unit test should return consistent results so the tests should be consistent

Comment: By that point, can you not just `Sort` the list before making assertions about it?

Comment: Is that the issue the ordering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a loop:

```
[Test]
public void SomethingSequenceNumberTest()
{
    var lotsOfThings = new List<Something>
    {
        new Something { SequenceNumber = 1 },
        new Something { SequenceNumber = 2 },
        new Something { SequenceNumber = 4 },
        new Something { SequenceNumber = 3 },
    };

    // Assert that a sequence of integer are incremental, that there are no repetitions or gaps.
    var index = lotsOfThings.First().SequenceNumber;
    lotsOfThings
        .OrderBy(t => t.SequenceNumber)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(t =>
        {
            Assert.That(t.SequenceNumber, Is.EqualTo(index));
            index++;
        });
}
```

Comment: This is the one I ended up using - apologies for my laziness, it;s just I've been coding solidly for about 14 hours with 5 hours sleep....

Comment: I would recommend to take a nap then :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, we can create a `LINQ` expression that should just return a sequence of `1`s. You should be able to build an assertion based on that:

```
var ordered = lotsOfThings.OrderBy(t=>t.SequenceNumber);

var final = ordered.Zip(ordered.Skip(1),(f,s)=>s-f);
```

(Not sure exactly which framework you're using but most should have some ability to `Assert` something about enumerables/collections. E.g. for MSTest, you'd use something from the [`CollectionAssert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.aspx) class)

(Up to you if you think it's worth optimizing this by adding `.ToList()` on the `ordered` definition. I don't usually micro-optimize tests and I assume we're not dealing with millions of items in the list. I also assume that you don't want to modify the original list, because there you could just `Sort()` it rather than introducing the LINQ `OrderBy`)

Answer (score 3):

Without a loop, two lines only.

```
var expected = Enumerable.Range(1, lotsOfThings.Count()).Select(i => i).ToArray();
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expected, lotsOfThings.Select(t => t.SequenceNumber).ToArray(), string.Join("; ", item));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through the list and add Assert inside loop..

```
var orderedList = list.OrderBy(a=>a.SequenceNumber);
var i = orderedList.First().SequenceNumber;

foreach(var item in orderedList)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(item.SequenceNumber, i++);
}
```

Comment: They give their *example* as a list with numbers 1, 2, 4, 3. How would this code succeed here? The whole point is that the numbers are *out of order* in the list, but the assertion they wish to make is that all numbers between 1-N (where N is the number of items in the list) has been assigned.

Comment: Updated the answer, we can simply handle that by adding `OrderBy` linq query.

Answer (score 2):

Another flavor:

```
[Test]
public void SomethingSequenceNumberTest()
{
    var lotsOfThings = new List<Something>
    {
        new Something { SequenceNumber = 1 },
        new Something { SequenceNumber = 2 },
        new Something { SequenceNumber = 4 },
        new Something { SequenceNumber = 3 },
    };

    // extract the sequence numbers into a list
    var sequenceNumbers = lotsOfThings.Select(x => x.SequenceNumber)                                   
                                      .ToList();
    sequenceNumbers.Sort();

    // Enumerable.Range will create a new enumerable
    // with values ranging from .First() to .Last(),
    // i.e. [1, 2, 3, 4]
    Assert.IsTrue(Enumerable.Range(sequenceNumbers.First(), sequenceNumbers.Last())
                            .SequenceEqual(sequenceNumbers));
}
```

How it works:

Subject to the sequence numbers being extracted to their own list (`sequenceNumbers`) and then sorted, this will use [`Enumerable.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netframework-4.7#System_Linq_Enumerable_Range_System_Int32_System_Int32_) to generate a sequence of integral numbers within a specified range (that range being the smaller and largest sequence numbers), and then use [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.7#System_Linq_Enumerable_SequenceEqual__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) to compare the generated enumerable against `sequenceNumbers` for equality (by using the default equality comparer for their type).

Answer (score 1):

We can loop through the whole collection and look back if the previous value is one smaller:

```
var incremental = true;

lotsOfThings = lotsOfThings.OrderBy(l => l.SequenceNumber).ToList();

for (var i = 0; i < lotsOfThings.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
        continue;

    var previous = lotsOfThings[i - 1].SequenceNumber;
    var current = lotsOfThings[i].SequenceNumber;

    // Great! The current one is 1 higher then the previous one, continue!
    if (previous == current - 1)
        continue;

    // Done checking, this list is not incrementing properly
    incremental = false;
    break;
}

Assert.IsTrue(incremental);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've come with my own implementation of such an assert method. This may be helpful if you need to do such assertion in several tests.

```
    public void AssertIsSequenced<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, int> valueExtractor)
    {
        int? lastExtractedValue = null;
        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            int extractedValue = valueExtractor(item);
            if (lastExtractedValue != null && extractedValue != lastExtractedValue + 1)
            {
                Assert.Fail($"{extractedValue} after {lastExtractedValue} does not follow the sequence rule.");
            }
            lastExtractedValue = extractedValue;
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SomethingSequenceNumberTest()
    {
        var lotsOfThings = new List<Something>
        {
            new Something { SequenceNumber = 1 },
            new Something { SequenceNumber = 2 },
            new Something { SequenceNumber = 4 },
            new Something { SequenceNumber = 3 },
        };

        // Assert that a sequence of integer are incremental, that there are no repetitions or gaps.

        AssertIsSequenced(lotsOfThings.OrderBy(something => something.SequenceNumber), something => something.SequenceNumber);
    }
```

Comment: Note that the `List` can be unordered.

Comment: Seems like I got the original question wrong. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Happened to me as well ;)